# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (2)

Tags: орфография

Предположим, я внесу "куда следует" следующее предложение: "Начиная с 1 января 2014 года, допускается включать в русский текст иноязычные слова "парашют", "парашютист" и т. п., но предпочтительнее включать в русский текст русские слова "парашут", "парашутист" и т. п."

**Вопрос:** "Противоречит ли моё предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?"

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Подобное предложение уже неоднократно озвучивалось, и в частности Лопатин предлагал убрать "Ю" после шипящих, в словах парашют, жюри и пр.. Мешает, в общем-то, только консерватизм носителей языка.

Comment: Не понял Вашего ответа. Например, следует ли рассматривать "консерватизм носителей языка" свойством русского языка?

Comment: Нет , это не свойство языка, это свойство его носителей. Написание парашют и жюри особенностям русской грамматики как раз противоречат.

Comment: Спасибо.

Я не знаю точную формулировку предложения В.В. Лопатина. Если Вы её знаете, тогда напишите её.

Comment: Марк Из (он же "историк, интересующийся русским языком") исказил предложение В.В. Лопатина. На самом деле, В.В. Лопатин предлагал:

1) писать "парашут" вместо "парашют", а также писать "брошура" вместо "брошюра",

2) сохранить правописание через "ю" слов: жюри, жюльен, пшют, шютте и т. п.